# What are the programs it needs to setup a software developed by C# and SQL Server 2005 on other PC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-3.5, deployment, setup-deployment

I have developed a software program using C# and SQL Server 2005 and I have published it but it does not want to be setup on any other personal computer as every time I install it on any PC, there is a problem about the SQL Server and another thing is called JAC

I don know how to make it installed, or if it requires any other help programs that should be installed on this PC

As this PC does not has any programs installed except the OS so is it requires any programs to be setup on this PC ?

Or what should I do to make it installed and run correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your program single-user? If so, then you might consider using SQL Server Compact / SQLite database, because they don't need to be installed; they are just tiny standalone libraries.
Then your user would just require .NET framework to be installed.

Comment: i just should download this Programs and setup them on the PC ,, then it will be installed and Run ??